# tar unzipping old file content

Tags: command-line, tar

Say I have a g zipped file named `test.tgz` with the content having a file named `hello.txt` and reads `hello world`.

I would unzip it using `tar -zxf` and make some modifications in `hello.txt` to read `hello.txt is modified`.

The issue is that when I try to unzip the original `test.tgz`, the unzipped file `hello.txt` *still* reads `hello.txt is modified`. How can the unzipped file not read `hello world`?

Answer (score 1):

I can't reproduce:

```
$ cd "$(mktemp --directory)"
$ echo 'hello world' > hello.txt
$ tar -czf test.tgz hello.txt
$ tar -zxf test.tgz
$ echo 'hello world is modified' > hello.txt
$ tar -zxf test.tgz
$ cat hello.txt
hello world
```

Please add more detailed info.

Comment: I'm operating a different file https://downloadseramba.s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/CommunityTGZ/latest.tgz - if I changed ./eramba_community/app/View/Layouts/default.ctp (AND unzip the original tgz again, I'd see the effected line INSTEAD of the original content)

Comment: @Bryan can you please write down exactly the commands you do to produce your result, just as l0b0 did in their post, and [**edit**](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/700376/edit) your question to include these command lines? Otherwise I'd say "well it works for all of us, and you're not detailed enough on what you do differently to help you", and that would be sad!